# html2canvas capture dynamic div content

Tags: html2canvas

Is there's a way to capture a dynamic div content using html2canvas ? Actually I'm using React-rnd in a div and I can't seem to capture the canvas content using html2canvas.

```
 Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.
```

I've tried some example from html2canvas but all I've got is white screen.